# How do I merge paragraphs in Joomla?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am making a page in Joomla and need to style the article background,
but there is a problem. I need only one paragraph, but Joomla creates a new paragraph after every "Enter." When I disable it, then there is just text and that is worse than multiple paragraphs.

```
<div class="items-row cols-1 row-1">
  <div class="item column-1">
    <h2> Hey, do you speak Financial English? </h2>
    <dl class="article-info">
    <p>
    <p>
    <div class="item-separator"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="row-separator"></span>
</div>
```

I there a way to merge all the paragraphs together? Or would it be a better solution to wrap them in a div?

thank you

...

thanks for your reply but, what if I have 150articles alredy created in db? ... and other articles will be added by other people, so I want to do it automaticaly maybe add  before first "p" and  after last "p" but css don't support html in before/after content so maybe I want to do it somehow in jQuery

Comment: that's weird - what editor you're using ? "no editor" ? cause any WYSIWYNG editor (tinymce for example) should let you edit the text as you want by clicking the "html" button and removing the <p></p> tags!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you want in joomla using "Shift + Enter".
This creates new lines without starting new paragraphs. Joomla might have an additional html editor - you can just remove the extra paragraphs it creates.

Comment: any other solution? for example jQuery wrap for "p" but i dont't know how to make it work in joomla

`<script>
  $(".items-row").each(function(index){
    jQuery(".items-row .row-"+ index +" .item p").wrapAll('<div class="pridany_div"></div>');
  });
   </script>`